# Chunking WebSocket Frames with Netty 3.5

Tags: netty

Looking through the Netty source I see all the support for chunking TextWebSocketFrames.  Meaning the continuation frames, the decoder handling and so on.  Though I am having a problem figuring out what to use to actually create the chunked frames, do I need to write this myself?  The encoder seems to be missing it and not sure how I would use the [ChunkedWriteHandler](http://netty.io/3.6/xref/org/jboss/netty/handler/stream/ChunkedWriteHandler.html) without extending it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to handle the writing of the frames by yourself, so it is up to you to send them in the right sequence and make sure you write them out in the correct order.